# Android How to save Button and TextView in dynamically view?

Tags: android

I am developing an app with a dynamic view.
You can write in an edittext and then you can tap a button to add the text in the edittext to a textview. Opposite of the textview is a button for deleting the textview. Now I want to make it so that the textview will save when the app closes.
I tested it with sharedpreference and many other ways.
Can you help me?

Source Code:

```
package com.studiocrew.lk;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

import android.view.View.*;
import android.content.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity

{
    EditText textIn;
    Button buttonAdd;
    Button buttonAddFirst;
    LinearLayout container;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textin);
    buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = 
                    (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                final View addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
                TextView textOut = (TextView)addView.findViewById(R.id.textout);
                textOut.setText(textIn.getText().toString());
                Button buttonRemove = (Button)addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);


}});

                container.addView(addView);
            }});

            buttonAddFirst = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addfirst);
            buttonAddFirst.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        buttonAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}});



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.Settings:
            Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code here? I'm pretty sure no one will download an unknown file and execute it on their devices...

Comment: Okey i had edit the post..:P sorry about that @ShobhitPuri

Comment: Like you mentioned, I would save this text in sharedPreference when the activity stops and retrieve it when it starts again. Do you still have your implementation of using sharedPreferences? Perhaps we can see why it didn't work for you.

Comment: Saving a value in SharedPreferences that isn't actually a Preference is bad design.  Use Bundles, like nature and Google intended.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about saving the TextView, but you can certainly save the content of the TextView in a Bundle to restore from onCreate().  Add a global field for the Bundle to reference:

```
private TextView inputOut;
```

Which is set dynamically in your buttonAdd.onClick()

And then save the state.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.puString(INPUT_CONTENT, textOut.getText().toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Then add this check for onCreate().

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String inputOut = savedInstanceState.getString(INPUT_CONTENT);
    } else {
        ....
    }
        ...
}
```

But if you really, really wanted to save the TextView object...

I would sub-class the TextView class and make it Parcelable/Serializable so that it could be added to a Bundle and restored from as above.

For example:

```
 public class MyTextView extends TextView implements Serializable {
      private String inputText;
      .....
      ....
      ...
 }
```

And override this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putSerialiazable(MY_TEXTVIEW, textOut);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Honestly not sure if that would work but in theory, yes?

Here is an article to help you choose Parcelable or Serializable, if you do try this:  http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Also this for saving state:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState